# Infinite/paginated scrolling with caching

Tags: ajax, pagination, browser-cache, infinite-scroll, javascript-framework

I have a requirement where I need to display a long table. It doesn't have to be displayed all at once, so ajax loading it is (load first 50 recs, then get another 50 rows everytime the user scrolls to/past the tenth row from the last).

But I'm not sure which of the two, pagination and infinite scrolling, is better. I'd like the user to be able to skip to the last scrolled-to point when returning to the page (through Back button, definitely; if I can do that whenever, however user visits the page, even better!) with the previous rows visible as well. At the same time, for performance, I want to restrict the number of ajax calls to as low as I can keep it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. To implement such scenerio, first consume an api with page no and number of records as request params in API calls
   For Ex- 'www.abc.com/v1/tableData/pageId=1&noOfRecords=50'
2. Then you will get the first 50 records. Its response should also provide you the total number of recors avaiallbe in database after callling first api .
3. When you scroll down, increase the pageId with +1
   For ex - 'www.abc.com/v1/tableData/pageId=2&noOfRecords=50'
4. In the same way, you will increase the pageId untill you check the total records you got till now, should be equals to the total records, you are getting from API key.
5. In this way you can able to impmentent it.
6. Talking about performance, its up to you whther you are using pagination or scroll, it does not matter, since you are restricting the number of records to display.